# C# Rotating JPG without losing too much quality

Tags: c#, resize, drawing, jpeg, rotation

So I'm reading in files from a directory, figuring out which way they need to be rotated.  Rotating and then saving.  That part works...  The issue is, after it saves the file it gets recompressed and I go from 1.5meg images to 250k images.  I need to keep the file size around the original.  I tried using jhead.exe and calling it from a command line but couldn't get any of my arguments to pass in correctly.  Here's my code snipit to detect, rotate, and save.

```
foreach (FileInfo f in dir.GetFiles("*.jpg"))
{
    try
    {
        string ExportName = "";

        Bitmap originalImage = new Bitmap(f.FullName.ToString());

        Info inf = new Info(originalImage);

        gma.Drawing.ImageInfo.Orientation orientation = gma.Drawing.ImageInfo.Orientation.TopLeft;
        try
        {
            orientation = inf.Orientation;
        }
        catch
        {
            orientation = gma.Drawing.ImageInfo.Orientation.TopLeft;
        }

        originalImage = CheckRotation(originalImage, orientation);

        progressBar.Value = progressBar.Value + 1;
        originalImage.Save(f.FullName.ToString(), ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        Application.DoEvents();


    }

private Bitmap CheckRotation(Bitmap inputImage, gma.Drawing.ImageInfo.Orientation orientation)
{

    Bitmap rotatedImage = inputImage;

    switch (orientation)
    {
        case gma.Drawing.ImageInfo.Orientation.LeftBottom:
            rotatedImage.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipXY);
            break;
        case gma.Drawing.ImageInfo.Orientation.RightTop:
            rotatedImage.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return rotatedImage;
}
```

Comment: I would advise you to use an open-source tool that performs lossless rotation (like jhead.exe appears to). Why don’t you open another question with the code you were using to run jhead?

Comment: You will need to use one of the `Save` overloads that takes an `ImageCodecInfo` and `EncoderParameters` - the parameters should include high quality in order to ensure that the image does not degrade significantly.

Comment: @Oded: You mean “does not degrade significantly”. There will virtually always be degradation when encoding an image as JPEG, even at “100%” quality. The format is lossy by definition.

Comment: @Oded: He said: “I tried using jhead.exe and calling it from a command line but couldn't get any of my arguments to pass in correctly.”

Comment: @Douglas - so he did. Missed that completely.

Comment: There are many other tools that will do lossless rotation as well. Here's a list of 84: http://jpegclub.org/losslessapps.html

Comment: Rotating a JPEG can be done completely lossless-ly...

Comment: If the original images which need to be rotated have an EXIF orientation tag, then the Q&D way to do it is to just change the single byte in the orientation tag. If you're dealing with viewers that ignore the orientation tag (cough *Windows* cough), then you will need to use one of the ideas mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders(); 
ImageCodecInfo ici = null; 

foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
{ 
    if (codec.MimeType == "image/jpeg") 
    ici = codec; 
} 

EncoderParameters ep = new EncoderParameters(); 
ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, (long)100);

originalImage.Save(f.FullName.ToString(), ici, ep);
```

This will use 100% quality - but beware, jpegs are still lossy compression - try using a png if you need loss-less quality.

Comment: That worked great.  Thank you.  I think I'm going to try again getting jhead to work.  It seems a bit faster.  But this plugged right in and worked.

Comment: I should point out - you don't need to look-up the jpeg codec each time - you should make sure your ici variable is cached outside any loops. Dave (and the 'ep' variable, for that matter)

Answer (score 2):

The key for lossless jpeg edit is to use always same QualityLevel and BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat | BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreColorProfile with BitmapCacheOption.None.

And be aware that even if you use QualityLevel 100, quality will go down. With this method goes down just first time, because it goes from unknown QualityLevel to 80, but every other jpeg edit is lossless.

```
RotateJpeg(@"d:\!test\TestInTest\20160209_143609.jpg", 80, Rotation.Rotate90);

public bool RotateJpeg(string filePath, int quality, Rotation rotation) {
  var original = new FileInfo(filePath);
  if (!original.Exists) return false;
  var temp = new FileInfo(original.FullName.Replace(".", "_temp."));

  const BitmapCreateOptions createOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat | BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreColorProfile;

  try {
    using (Stream originalFileStream = File.Open(original.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
      JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder {QualityLevel = quality, Rotation = rotation};

      //BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat | BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreColorProfile and BitmapCacheOption.None
      //is a KEY to lossless jpeg edit if the QualityLevel is the same
      encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(originalFileStream, createOptions, BitmapCacheOption.None));

      using (Stream newFileStream = File.Open(temp.FullName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite)) {
        encoder.Save(newFileStream);
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception) {
    return false;
  }

  try {
    temp.CreationTime = original.CreationTime;
    original.Delete();
    temp.MoveTo(original.FullName);
  }
  catch (Exception) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: This method works very well.  Tested with a 4.3Mb jpg.  First rotation decreased size to 980Kb.  Visually comparing original to rotated, even zooming in quite far, images nearly identical. Outstanding results. Subsequent rotations were indeed lossless, and kept image size to 980Kb.  Also tested QualityLevel at 90 then 100; image quality results same, but with larger file size than QualityLevel 80.  QualityLevel 90 reduced file size to 1.7Mb, and oddly QualityLevel 100 increased file size to 6.3Mb.  Happy with QualityLevel 80 and file size that is one quarter the original file size.  Nice job!

Comment: Initial testing as mentioned above was done on a pic of an electric guitar.  Will do more testing with different file types, as I will be using this with a scanning app.  Maybe all the noise in scanned images will make for more noticeable image quality differences after rotation, but so far, so good!

Comment: Same results on scanned images; this is an excellent solution.

Answer (score 1):

Easy...

```
public static void Rotate90(string fileName)
{ 
    Image Pic; 
    string FileNameTemp; 
    Encoder Enc = Encoder.Transformation; 
    EncoderParameters EncParms = new EncoderParameters(1); 
    EncoderParameter EncParm; 
    ImageCodecInfo CodecInfo = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg"); 
 
    // load the image to change 
    Pic = Image.FromFile(fileName); 
 
    // we cannot store in the same image, so use a temporary image instead 
    FileNameTemp = fileName + ".temp"; 

    // for rewriting without recompression we must rotate the image 90 degrees
    EncParm = new EncoderParameter(Enc,(long)EncoderValue.TransformRotate90); 
    EncParms.Param[0] = EncParm; 

    // now write the rotated image with new description 
    Pic.Save(FileNameTemp,CodecInfo,EncParms); 
    Pic.Dispose(); 
    Pic = null; 

    // delete the original file, will be replaced later 
    System.IO.File.Delete(fileName); 
    System.IO.File.Move(FileNameTemp, fileName); 
}
```

See reference at:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-transforming-a-jpeg-image-without-loss-of-information-use