# What is the reason of decreasing the image size when rotating with Image.RotateFlip() in C#?

Tags: c#

I have an application that showing the pictures uploading from the system. For that I have to rotate while uploading portrait images. Initially when I rotate the size of the image was increased and image meta data was lost. Then I passed the image format as a parameter when saving the image.

```
 myImage.Save(<ImagePath>, <Image Format>);
```

But now the file size is decreasing nearly 50%.

```
        using (Image image = Image.FromFile(sourceFileName))
            {
                int oritentation = (int)image.GetPropertyItem(274).Value[0];
                RotateFlipType rotatedFlipAngle = RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone;
                switch (oritentation)
                {
                    case 3:
                        rotatedFlipAngle = RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        rotatedFlipAngle = RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipX;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        rotatedFlipAngle = RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipX;
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        rotatedFlipAngle = RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone;
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        rotatedFlipAngle = RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipX;
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        rotatedFlipAngle = RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone;
                        break;
                }
                var rawFormat = image.RawFormat;
                if (_rotatedFlipAngle != RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone)
                {
                    image.RotateFlip(_rotatedFlipAngle);
                    image.Save(fileName), rawFormat);
                }
            }
```

what is the problem of reducing the original size of the image? 
Thanks.

Comment: I think this relates to the default compression level. You should be able to set it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-set-jpeg-compression-level?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505608/c-sharp-rotating-jpg-without-losing-too-much-quality). Seems like your file is compressing while you save it again, and it is not depends on rotating

Answer (score 1):

It is actually not depend on rotating your image. Quality decrease because of saving file again with compression.

You can setup compression level manually that way:

```
using (Image image = Image.FromFile(sourceFileName))
        {
            int oritentation = (int)image.GetPropertyItem(274).Value[0];
            RotateFlipType rotatedFlipAngle = RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone;
            switch (oritentation)
            {
                case 3:
                    rotatedFlipAngle = RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    rotatedFlipAngle = RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipX;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    rotatedFlipAngle = RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipX;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    rotatedFlipAngle = RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    rotatedFlipAngle = RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipX;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    rotatedFlipAngle = RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone;
                    break;
            }

            ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders(); 
            ImageCodecInfo ici = null; 

            foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
            { 
                if (codec.MimeType == "image/jpeg") 
                ici = codec; 
            } 

            EncoderParameters ep = new EncoderParameters(); 
            ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, (long)100)


            if (_rotatedFlipAngle != RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone)
            {
                image.RotateFlip(_rotatedFlipAngle);
                image.Save(fileName), ici, ep);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Mateech. But now the image size is increasing 2 times. Have you any idea on it?

Comment: @IKSU you can change `EncoderParameter` settings for achieve result you need.  A quality level of 0 corresponds to the greatest compression, and a quality level of 100 corresponds to the least compression. Try to set 75 at first.